# SSRS URL Access slower than Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using URL access to embed a report in an application using a URL that looks something like this:

```
https://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportPath/&parameter=value
```

This report has several parameters whose valid values are populated by queries.

The report is displayed in about the same amount of time as it takes when accessing the report via Report Manager.

However, I've noticed that if I change a parameter in Report Manager and click the "View Report" button, it refreshes a few seconds faster than if I refresh the report by URL access.

I assume this is because refreshing the report in Report Manager cuts out some processing steps. It looks like a bunch of state is sent back to the server when you refresh the report using the "View Report" button in Report Manager, whereas I presume refreshing the report via URL access is essentially doing all of the work from scratch.

Are my assumptions correct? Is there any way I can refresh a report with new parameters via URL access just as quickly as it does when using Report Manager?

Comment: One thing I have noticed about reporting services-and this is very odd being it is a microsoft product-is it runs a LOT faster in google chrome.  Especially on a busy report that includes cascading parameters.  Try it out side by side with IE and chrome.  When you change a parameter using chrome it flies, change that same parameter in IE and it is slower then molasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assumptions are correct, as far as I know the Report Manager and ReportViewer controls will have a session spanning multiple requests. (Although I'm a bit surprised this would also work when you change the parameters, because I can't imagine what steps could be skipped in that case.)

To control this, the Report Manager uses sessions. Even though I haven't tried it myself, you should be able to do this with URLS by [using the SessionId and related parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153610%28v=sql.105%29).

Let us know if this worked for you!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the SessionID and related parameters. I wasn't aware of them. Unfortunately, it still looks like the report is processed from scratch when refreshing via a URL, even if I pass in the same SessionID between requests. But for giving me a promising lead, you get my vote. Working with sessions still might bear fruit, but for now, we've decided to defer this issue.